# SSRS - only allow monetary value in parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I'm creating an SSRS package that requires my end user to enter a monetary value into a parameter.  Is there anyway you can make it so that they can only enter numbers in?  Is there also a way to make it so that the value I default it to be shows 0.00?  Every time I try to input the value it defaults to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your data type of your parameter as 'Integer' [image]

You can then add a default Value with a function [image]

```
=FormatCurrency(Fields!SomeField.Value, "C")
```

Hope that helps